# Is an authorization header required by the azure storage shared access signature (SAS) REST API

Tags: azure-storage

I need to read/write an azure storage table.
The client program is configured to use a shared access signature to read/write remote azure table.

Can anyone give me a good example of how to construct the authorization header in order to use the sas?
I am getting HTTP error code 403.

Microsoft documentation specified that all the rest API will have to be embedded with an authorization header. By default, the documentation suggests that I can use the storage account access key to generate the HMAC-SHA code for the authorization header. I think I am missing something here.

The whole idea of using a shared access signature (SAS) is to protect the storage account access key. At the same time, the doeumentation seems to suggest that the storage account owner needs to provide the account access key so the client can use the access key to generate the HMAC-SHA code. What am I missing here? can anyone shed some light here? Thanks,

Comment: Could please let us know which api you're using? you can provide a link to the api. I can provide a working example here.

Comment: are you using azure table storage [Query Entities api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-entities)?

Comment: Yes, I am using the query entity api, Here is the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-entities

Comment: provided that I am using SAS,  Microsoft keeps telling me that I don't need to provide an authorization header. It seems pretty straight forward. Yet, I keep getting HTTP error 403.   I suspects that maybe there is a problem with the header?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using `sas_token` in the `request url`, then you don't need to provide `Authorization` in the header.

How to check which header should be provided? in the [related api page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-entities) -> go to the [Request Headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-entities#request-headers) section -> check each header, if the header is required, then it will be described in it's Description. Here is a screenshot for your reference:

[image]

**Here are the steps to query entities by using sas_token:**

1.Generate sas_token from azure portal. You can refer to the screenshot below:

[image]

2.Check which header are required, as per [query-entities -> request-headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-entities#request-headers), we know `x-ms-date` is required(`Authorization` is not required here since we're using sas_token). You can provide a value for `x-ms-date`, like `Wed, 13 Jan 2021 01:29:31 GMT`.

If you don't know how to get the value for `x-ms-date` header, you can open powershell -> type `Get-Date` command -> then it will generate the date:

[image]

3.Prepare the request url with sas_token, like below:

[https://xxx.table.core.windows.net/testtable(PartitionKey='a1',RowKey='r11')?sv=2019-12-12&ss=t&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacu&se=2021-01-13T09:24:58Z&st=2021-01-13T01:24:58Z&spr=https&sig=xxxxx](https://xxx.table.core.windows.net/testtable(PartitionKey=%27a1%27,RowKey=%27r11%27)?sv=2019-12-12&ss=t&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacu&se=2021-01-13T09:24:58Z&st=2021-01-13T01:24:58Z&spr=https&sig=xxxxx)

4.Use some tools like [Postman](https://www.postman.com/downloads/), send the request with proper header. Here is the test result by using `Postman`:

[image]

Comment: Let me run a quick test. I am really using entity rest API to read/write. You are absolutely right about the authorization header. Provided that I am using a shared access signature, there is absolutely no need to include the authorization header.   However, I am still getting HTTP error 403.  I am guessing that I am missing something about the must-have header. I see the screenshot from your postman. Let me see if my postman can produce the same result. I do see that you input your own header (x-ms-date) instead of using the postman default parameters.  Thanks for the solution.